# Get posts with Ajax posts filter with multi selection checkboxes

Tags: php, html, arrays, ajax, wordpress

I am trying to achieve **an ajax post filter** with a form which use **muti-selection checkboxes**. *I have shortened the form with only 3 groups of 4 checkboxes each (instead of 11 groups).*

Here my filter have 3 **groups** *(master keys)* which are **`brand`**, **`ram`** and **`price`**, and every group have 4 different key / values *(checkboxes)*. Each checkbox in the group can be checked *(multi-selection)*

> Here is the live link for this project, and if you check with your browser console tools, you will see that the data is correctly sent by jQuery and received by my php function.

**This is working:**
The **`HTML`** file with all the checkboxes is working fine with my ajax jQuery script and it **sends correctly** an array of key/values to my php function. I have correctly registered my jQuery script and used as well as

**The array of data received** *(for 2 checked checkboxes for example of the same group)*:

```
$choices = array( 'brand1' => 'Nokia', 'brand3' => 'Sony' );**`wp_localize_script()`**…
```

> **What is not working yet:**
>
>   - Prepare the data for the **`WP_query()`**
>   - The query herself **`$args`** array

How to manage call_post() function, after that it get value from JS and disply posts using loop??**

> The PHP code in **`function.php`**:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_call_post', 'call_post');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_call_post', 'call_post');
function call_post(){

$choices = $_POST['choices'];
print_r($_POST['choices']);
foreach($choices as $name => $choice)
    $fam = explode('-', $name);
    $family = $fam[0];       
}

$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
        array(
            'key' => 'brand',
            'value' => $brand,
        ) ,
         array(
            'key' => 'ram',
            'value' => $ram,
        ) ,
         array(
            'key' => 'price',
            'value' => $price,
    ) ,
);

$query = new WP_Query($args);
    if( $query->have_posts() ) :
        while( $query->have_posts() ): $query->the_post();
          echo file_get_contents(locate_template("content.php"));
        endwhile;
        wp_reset_query();
    else :
        wp_send_json($query->posts);
    endif;
 die();
}
```

> Script

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('#phones-filter .br').click(function(){

        var choices = {}; // declaring an empty array
        var choice = $(this).attr('name');
        $('.contents').remove();
        $('.filter-output').empty();

        // scanning each checkbox for checked state data
        $('div > li > .br').each(function(index, obj) {
            if($(this).prop('checked')){
                var name = $(this).attr('name'), val = $(this).val();
                choices[name] = val;
            }
        });

        $.ajax({
            url: ajaxobject.ajaxurl,
            type :'POST',
            data : {
                'action' : 'call_post',
                'choices' : choices,
            },
            success: function (result) {
                $(choice).appendTo('.filter-output');
                console.log(result);
                console.log(choices);
            },
            error: function(err){
                console.log(err);
                console.log(choices);
            }
        });
    })
});
```

> Form.php *(shortened)*

```
<form  id="phones-filter" >
<div class="brand">
        <li><input type="checkbox" name="brand-1" value="Nokia" class="br"> NOKIA </li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" name="brand-2" value="LG" class="br"> LG </li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" name="brand-3" value="Sony" class="br"> Sony </li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" name="brand-4" value="Apple" class="br"> Apple </li>
</div>
<div class="ram">
        <li> <input type="checkbox" name="ram-1" value="1GB" class="br"> 1 GB  </li>
         <li><input type="checkbox" name="ram-2" value="2GB" class="br"> 1 GB  </li>
         <li><input type="checkbox" name="ram-3" value="3GB" class="br"> 2 GB  </li>
         <li><input type="checkbox" name="ram-3" value="4GB" class="br"> 4 GB    </li>
</div>
<div class="price">
        <li><input type="checkbox" name="price-1" value="$100" class="br"> $100 </li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" name="price-2" value="$200" class="br"> $200 </li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" name="price-3" value="$300" class="br"> $300 </li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" name="price-4" value="$500" class="br"> $400 </li>
</div>
<div class="filter-output"></div>
</form>
```

> content.php

```
    <div <?php post_class( 'col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-6 ' ); ?> id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
    <div class="single-post"> 

               <div class="post-thumb" > 
                        <a href="<?php echo esc_url( post_permalink() ); ?>">
                            <?php the_post_thumbnail  ( 'large', array(
                                    'class' => 'img-responsive' 
                            ) ); ?> 
                            </a>
                </div>  

        <div class="post-info">     
            <div class="post-title"><li><a href="<?php echo esc_url( post_permalink() ); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li></div>                    
            <div class="rs"><p><?php echo get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'price', true ); ?><?php _e( '', 'mobilewebsite' ); ?></p></div>         
        </div> 

    </div>                                 
</div>
<?php $item_number++;
 if( $item_number % 2 == 0 ) echo '<div class="clearfix visible-xs-block"></div>';
 if( $item_number % 4 == 0 ) echo '<div class="clearfix visible-sm-block"></div>';
 if( $item_number % 6 == 0 ) echo '<div class="clearfix visible-md-block"></div>'; 
 if( $item_number % 6 == 0 ) echo '<div class="clearfix visible-md-block"></div>'; 
 ?>
```

Comment: get_template_part('content'); is return html?

Comment: @vel Nothing return,

Comment: you should print the content otherwise ajax response will be empty

Comment: Please more clear, or give me answer

Comment: can you post the content.php?

Comment: @vel i attached content.php in question

Comment: have you check query have post?

Comment: try this. while( $query->have_posts() ): $query->the_post();  echo "test";

Comment: Its come within loop?

Comment: now i try.. but nothing output

Comment: function call_post() is that OK for you??

Comment: what is the value $params array?

Comment: $params is to add content.php

Comment: remove this if( ! empty ($params['template'])) {
    $template = $params['template']; and add this  echo "test"; after while( $query->have_posts() ): $query->the_post();

Comment: ok, i also update my question

Comment: add this echo "test"; after while( $query->have_posts() ): $query->the_post();

Comment: seems your site not working. i think php syntax error. remove one } in call_post function

Comment: now i aslo unable to access wp_admin too.. after editing

Comment: remove one } in call_post function

Comment: site error, after removing $params.. Now i work offline server

Comment: i removes.. this is really a mistake

Comment: or echo file_get_contents(locate_template("content.php"));

Comment: i update my function.php, check in question.. not working.. why??

Comment: remove all meta query from args and try $args = array(  'post_type' => 'post').

Comment: sill not working,,, i update function.php same as i using localy... please check function

Comment: remove one } in call_post function.... site error because of this.. these two are valid one for end

Comment: Now console pass the whole content.php file

Comment: please upload in online server. So i can check

Comment: currently server is offline.. i will text you as its working.. please give me some time.

Comment: ok. let me know once working

Comment: i get back my site.. please visit

Comment: but its not  above the code

Comment: Let me give sometimes.

Comment: @vel please comments something  about solution

Comment: Im on the way to home. I will comment you once i reached

Comment: seems working fine. you didnt pass the value for $brand and... so its not worked. I cannot access your script.js file via wp-admin. so I cannot fix. let me know once see this comment. sent you invite in hangout.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with below code

```
<form  id='test' >
    <strong>Brand</strong>
    <div class="brand">
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="brand" value="Nokia" class="br"> NOKIA </li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="brand" value="LG" class="br"> LG </li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="brand" value="Sony" class="br"> Sony </li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="brand" value="Apple" class="br"> Apple </li>
    </div>
    <strong>Ram</strong>
    <div class="ram">
            <li> <input type="checkbox" name="ram" value="1GB" class="br"> 1 GB  </li>
             <li><input type="checkbox" name="ram" value="2GB" class="br"> 1 GB  </li>
             <li><input type="checkbox" name="ram" value="3GB" class="br"> 2 GB  </li>
             <li><input type="checkbox" name="ram" value="4GB" class="br"> 4 GB    </li>
    </div>
    <strong>Price</strong>
    <div class="price">
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="price" value="$100" class="br"> $100 </li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="price" value="$200" class="br"> $200 </li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="price" value="$300" class="br"> $300 </li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="price" value="$500" class="br"> $400 </li>
    </div>
</form>




    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
        $('#test .br').click(function(){

            // declaring an array
            var choices = {};

            $('.contents').remove();
            $('.filter-output').empty()

            $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').each(function() {
                if (!choices.hasOwnProperty(this.name)) 
                    choices[this.name] = [this.value];
                else 
                    choices[this.name].push(this.value);
            });


            console.log(choices);
            $.ajax({
                url: ajaxobject.ajaxurl,
                type :'POST',
                data : {
                    'action' : 'call_post', // the php name function
                    'choices' : choices,
                },
                success: function (result) {
                    $('.filter-output').append(result);
                    // just for test - success (you can remove it later)
                    //console.log(result);
                    //console.log(choices);
                },
                error: function(err){
                    // just for test - error (you can remove it later)
                    console.log(err);
                    console.log(choices);
                }
            });
        })
    });




add_action('wp_ajax_call_post', 'call_post');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_call_post', 'call_post');

function call_post(){

    // Getting the ajax data:
    // An array of keys("name")/values of each "checked" checkbox
    $choices = $_POST['choices'];

    $meta_query = array('relation' => 'OR');
    foreach($choices as $Key=>$Value){

        if(count($Value)){
            foreach ($Value as $Inkey => $Invalue) {
                $meta_query[] = array( 'key' => $Key, 'value' => $Invalue, 'compare' => '=' );
            }
        }
    }
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'meta_query' =>$meta_query
    );

    $query = new WP_Query($args);
     //if( ! empty ($params['template'])) {
         ////$template = $params['template'];
         if( $query->have_posts() ) :
             while( $query->have_posts() ): $query->the_post();
                 get_template_part('content');
             endwhile;
             wp_reset_query();
         else :
             wp_send_json($query->posts);
         endif;
     //}

    die();
}
```