# Use multiple 'relation' arguments in AJAX post filter function

Tags: php, html, arrays, ajax, wordpress

I am trying to achieve an ajax post filter with a form which use **muti-selection** through groups of checkboxes.

This filter have **5 groups** (master keys) which are **`brand`**, **`ram`**, **`camera`**, **`price`** and  **`feature`**. Every group have between 4 and 5 different key / value (checkboxes).

> For the moment, this works in **mono-selection mode** only: 
>   If I chose 2 checkboxes of the same group, **nothing is displayed…**

**How can I enable multi-selection for this groups of checkboxes?**

Here is the php function that make the Ajax query:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_call_post', 'call_post');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_call_post', 'call_post');

function call_post(){

$choices = $_POST['choices'];

$meta_query = array('relation' => 'AND');
foreach($choices as $Key=>$Value){

    if(count($Value)){
        foreach ($Value as $Inkey => $Invalue) {
            $meta_query[] = array( 'key' => $Key, 'value' => $Invalue, 'compare' => 'like' );
        }
    }
}
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'meta_query' =>$meta_query
 );

$query = new WP_Query($args);
     if( $query->have_posts() ) :
         while( $query->have_posts() ): $query->the_post();
             get_template_part('content');
         endwhile;
         wp_reset_query();
     else :
  _e('Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.');
         wp_send_json($query->posts);
     endif;
die();
}
?>
```

Here are the html form and the javascript, that are used in this thread:
[Get posts with Ajax posts filter with multi selection checkboxes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39130444/get-posts-with-ajax-posts-filter-with-multi-selection-checkboxes)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> To achieve this you need:
>
> - to group actions data by groups *(selected checkboxes)*
> - to include in each group of arrays a **`'relation' => 'OR'`** *(**only** if the group has more than one check-box selected)*

Your php function will be like this:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_call_post', 'call_post');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_call_post', 'call_post');

function call_post(){

    $choices = $_POST['choices'];

    // Defining here your fields groups
    $groups = array('brand', 'ram', 'camera', 'price', 'feature');

    // Grouping data by group
    foreach($choices as $Key => $Value){
        foreach ($Value as $Inkey => $Invalue) {
            switch ($Key) {

                // One block for each group defined in $groups array

                case $groups[0]:
                    $grp[0][] = array( 'key' => $Key, 'value' => $Invalue, 'compare' => 'like' );
                    break;

                case $groups[1]:
                    $grp[1][] = array( 'key' => $Key, 'value' => $Invalue, 'compare' => 'like' );
                    break;

                case $groups[2]:
                    $grp[2][] = array( 'key' => $Key, 'value' => $Invalue, 'compare' => 'like' );;
                    break;

                case $groups[3]:
                    $grp[3][] = array( 'key' => $Key, 'value' => $Invalue, 'compare' => 'like' );
                    break;

                case $groups[4]:
                    $grp[4][] = array( 'key' => $Key, 'value' => $Invalue, 'compare' => 'like' );
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    $grp_arr = array();

    // Adding ('relation' => 'OR') to each group with a length > 1
    foreach ($grp as $key_grp => $grp_values) {
        if(count($grp_values) > 1){
            $grp_arr[$key_grp] = array('relation' => 'OR');
        }
        foreach ($grp_values as $grp_val) {
            $grp_arr[$key_grp][] = $grp_val;
        }
    }
    
    // Compiling it all
    $meta_query = array('relation' => 'AND');
    foreach ($grp_arr as $grp_arr_val) {
        $meta_query[] = $grp_arr_val;
    }

    // The query (compiled)
    $query = new WP_Query( array(
        'post_type'     => 'post',
        'meta_query'    => $meta_query
    ) );

    // The Loop
    if( $query->have_posts() ) :
        while( $query->have_posts() ): $query->the_post();
            get_template_part('content');
        endwhile;
        wp_reset_query();!
    else :
        _e('Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.');
        wp_send_json($query->posts);
    endif;

    die();
}
```

So you will get this kind of formatted array:

```
$query = array(
    'post_type'    => 'product',
    'meta_query'   => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'relation' => 'OR',
            array(
                'key'     => 'brand',
                'value'   => 'Nokia',
                'compare' => 'like',
            ),
            array(
                'key'     => 'brand',
                'value'   => 'LG',
                'compare' => 'like',
            ),
        ),
        array(
            'relation' => 'OR',
            array(
                'key'     => 'ram',
                'value'   => '1GB',
                'compare' => 'like',
            ),
            array(
                'key'     => 'ram',
                'value'   => '2GB',
                'compare' => 'like',
            ),
        ),
    ),
);
```

So This should work as expected, to enable multi-selection by group of checkboxes…