# Filter custom post with multiple checkboxes via AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I'm working on multiple filters functionality in Wordpress page.
I have done selectors and AJAX query, and get data correct (I think). But result of AJAX function is wrong - every request result is every not-filtered post.

My code:

```
<div class="filters">
                    <h4 class="products__filters--name">Product series</h4>
            <ul class="products__filters--list">
                                                      <li>
                      <input class="products__filters--checkbox" type="checkbox" name="product_series" value="Castillo">
                                                                      Castillo
                      <span class="checkmark"></span>
                    </li>
                                                      <li>
                      <input class="products__filters--checkbox" type="checkbox" name="product_series" value="Robinia">
                                                                      Robinia
                      <span class="checkmark"></span>
                    </li>
                                                      <li>
                      <input class="products__filters--checkbox" type="checkbox" name="product_series" value="Test">
                                                                      Test
                      <span class="checkmark"></span>
                    </li>
                                                      <li>
                      <input class="products__filters--checkbox checked" type="checkbox" name="product_series" value="Wooden">
                                                                      Wooden
                      <span class="checkmark"></span>
                    </li>
                            </ul>
                    <h4 class="products__filters--name">Colors</h4>
            <ul class="products__filters--list">
                                                      <li>
                      <input class="products__filters--checkbox" type="checkbox" name="colors" value="blue">
                                                                          <div class="products__filters--color" style="background: #8c8c8c;"></div>
                                              blue
                      <span class="checkmark"></span>
                    </li>
                                                      <li>
                      <input class="products__filters--checkbox checked" type="checkbox" name="colors" value="red">
                                                                      red
                      <span class="checkmark"></span>
                    </li>
                            </ul>
                    <h4 class="products__filters--name">Age group</h4>
            <ul class="products__filters--list">
                                                      <li>
                      <input class="products__filters--checkbox" type="checkbox" name="age_group" value="1-3">
                                                                      1-3
                      <span class="checkmark"></span>
                    </li>
                                                      <li>
                      <input class="products__filters--checkbox checked" type="checkbox" name="age_group" value="4-7">
                                                                      4-7
                      <span class="checkmark"></span>
                    </li>
                            </ul>
                <div class="button base js-filter-search">Search</div>
    </div>
```

JS Code:

```
      (function ($) {
      $(document).ready(function (){
        $(document).on('click', '.js-filter-search', function (e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          var choices = {};
          var choice = $('.products__filters--checkbox:checked').attr('name');

          $('.products__filters--checkbox:checked').each(function() {
                         if (!choices.hasOwnProperty(this.name))
                             choices[this.name] = [this.value];
                         else
                             choices[this.name].push(this.value);
                     });
          console.log(choices);


          var ppp = -1;
          var url = window.location.origin;

          $.ajax({
            url: url.concat('/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php'),
            data: {action: 'filterproducts', termNames:choices, ppp:ppp },
            type: 'post',
            success: function(result) {
              $('.js-products-result').html(result);
            },
            error: function (result) {
              console.warn(result);
            }
          })
        })
      })
    })(jQuery);
```

and PHP request:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_filterproducts', 'filterproducts_ajax');
add_action('wp_ajax_filterproducts', 'filterproducts_ajax');


function filterproducts_ajax() {


   header("Content-Type: text/html");
    $ppp = $_POST['ppp'];
    $termNames = $_POST['termNames'];
    $tax_query = array('relation' => 'OR');
      foreach($termNames as $key=>$value){
        if(count($value)){
          foreach ($value as $inkey => $invalue) {
            $tax_query[] = array( 'taxonomy' => $key, 'terms' => $invalue, 'field' => 'name');
          }
        }
      }

      var_dump($tax_query);
      $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'products',
            'meta_query' =>$tax_query
        );

    $query = new WP_Query($args);
      if( $query->have_posts() ) :
        while( $query->have_posts() ): $query->the_post();?>

          <div class="products__item">
           <a href="<?php echo get_permalink($product);?>"  class="products__item--title"><?php echo get_the_title($product);?></a>
          </div>
     <?php
     endwhile;
   endif;
   wp_reset_postdata();
   die();
 }
```

Output of var_dump($tax_query):

```
array (size=3)
  'relation' => string 'OR' (length=2)
  0 => 
    array (size=3)
      'taxonomy' => string 'product_series' (length=14)
      'terms' => string 'Robinia' (length=7)
      'field' => string 'name' (length=4)
  1 => 
    array (size=3)
      'taxonomy' => string 'colors' (length=6)
      'terms' => string 'blue' (length=4)
      'field' => string 'name' (length=4)
```

finally I'm stuck in the result of query - output is all of my Products CPT repeated 4 times after all $tax_query dump.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. I'm also surprised you don't get an error for headers already sent.

Comment: @HowardE no, for headers I receive an array. I don't know how to filter my WP_query with this data. 
I was working with that thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39130444/get-posts-with-ajax-posts-filter-with-multi-selection-checkboxes as an reference.

Comment: Is it a tax_query or a meta_query?

Comment: to be honest I don't know which one to use.

Comment: but I think it should be a tax_query @HowardE

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? Is this a PHP problem, or a jQuery problem?

Comment: @NicoHaase - I made it and pasted my resolve below ;)

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, I made it.
Below I share my code, maybe somebody use it.

```
$tax_query = array('relation' => 'AND');

 foreach($_POST['termNames'] as $key => $terms) {
   if(count($terms)) {
     foreach ($terms as $inkey => $invalue) {
       $tax_query[] = array( 'taxonomy' => $key, 'field' => 'name', 'terms' => $invalue);
     }
   }
 }
 $args = array(
   'post_type' => 'products',
   'tax_query' =>$tax_query
 );
  $query = new WP_Query($args);
    if( $query->have_posts() ) :
      while( $query->have_posts() ): $query->the_post(); ?>
       // here your post tile code
  else :
    echo "Sorry, no products was found";
  endif;
wp_reset_postdata();
```